# Take result from one query / mutation and pipe to another

Tags: graphql

I'm wondering if there's a way in GraphiQL that will let me pipe the result from one query / mutation into another query / mutation. Here's an example where the `login` mutation is used to get a `viewer` and the `viewer` would be used to query the `addresses` for that user. Is this possible with GraphQL / GraphiQL.

```
mutation {
  login(credentials: {
    email: "me@me.com",
    password: "password123",
    passwordConfirmation: "password123"
  }) {
    viewer
  }
}

query {
  addresses(viewer:viewer) {
    city
  }
}
```

Comment: There's an experimental batchOperations feature but I don't think it's landed in graphql-js yet. I opened a issue here. https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the selection set in the mutations is to be able to fetch data that has changed as a result of the mutation. But it also makes it possible to fetch related data, as long as you can access is through the mutation result type.

Let's assume we have following types:

```
type Address {
  city: String
}
type User {
  addresses: [Address]
}
```

If the result (payload) type of the `login` mutation includes a field `viewer` of type `User` that refers to the successfully logged in user, you can query any field of the `User` in the result of the mutation:

```
mutation {
  login(credentials: {
    email: "me@me.com",
    password: "password123",
    passwordConfirmation: "password123"
  }) {
    viewer {
      addresses {
        city
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the case above the viewer is an id or token that allows you to access other pieces of the API. What your saying makes sense, but it doesn't help me. I need to still make one request get the viewer (token) then copy and paste it in as an argument for other mutations, which is a bummer.

Comment: I think for queries, you need a "User" type that represents the logged in user and add the fields related to the user in that type. Then you can add a reference to `User` in the mutation result type, so you can query it.

For mutations, as you said, it's true that you can't batch mutations that depend on a result of a previous mutation inside GraphQL, but it should be possible to build a batch endpoint that does this at outside the query language, in your HTTP server.

Comment: I think It's coming, just not ready yet. github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462